# Scope of return value of a function in C

Tags: c

```
int Mul (int x)
{
   int y =0;
   y = x *3;
   return y;
}

int Main(void)
{   
   int var =0;
   scanf ("%d", &var);
   int result =0;
   result = Mul(var);
   printf ("%d", result);
}
```

Now my question is:
The variable `y` is created on the stack and when the function `Mul` returns, it gets cleared. Then how it is assigned to result?

```
result = Mul(var);
```

Comment: A copy of the value of `y` is returned and assigned; it doesn't matter that the memory originally holding the local variable is invalid because the value was copied.  You run into problems when you return a pointer to a local variable; the pointer is copied back safely, but it is unusable because what it points at is no longer valid.

Comment: The value is returned. Also in c, everything is converted to address at compile time; at runtime, almost no concept of symbol name.

Comment: ... depends on the function calling convention as to how it is compiled into assembly and then assembled ... for a simple return value (like int y ) then it is usually returned in one of the CPU core registers, and so it doesn't need the stack any more from the function that just executed ... if the function is simple it could even never appear in the stack after optimisation, so just could use only register(s)

Answer (score 0):

C considers the function "Mul" to have this value upon return, as though it were a variable.  Note that Mul is declared as an int.  Using "return" puts the value of y on the stack to be used in the assignment to "result".  This value is popped from the stack which in effect clears it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement
        return y;
Does not return the value of y but a copy of the value of y. This copy is stored in the result variable. When you execute the code again with new values for x and y, the old values are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are returning the value of the variable (y) not the variable it self. Also variable "y" is local to mul function , so you cant return "y" as its scope is local to that function.
2. Whenever there is function call other than the void data type, the function call statement is replaced by the value that function is returning.

For eg.

In your case if 
    x=3
then 
    y= 3*3 evaluates to 9
thus

```
y=9
```

and

```
return y
```

simply means return 9 just like you return 0.

so the expression

```
result=mul(var) //is replaced by result=9.
```

I think this is enough of explanation